# Postgres - updating millions of rows

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-performance, plpgsql

I am trying to update a column in a table with around 30 millions of rows without downtime.

To do that, I am not dropping indexes and constraints because I want to keep the table working normally during the entire process and I am chunking the table in a Procedure which is committing each 5000 rows.

```
-- My procedure =)
create or replace procedure set_my_new_column_in_my_table()
language plpgsql
as
$$
    declare
        _index int4 := 1;
        _processed int4 := 0;
        _total int4 := 0;
        _is_done boolean := false;
        _chunk_size int4 := 5000;

        _start_time timestamptz;
        _end_time timestamptz;
        _delta double precision;

        _i_start_time timestamptz;
        _i_end_time timestamptz;
        _i_delta double precision;
    begin
        _start_time := clock_timestamp();
        raise notice 'Starting: my_table Migration...';
        raise notice '------------------------------------------------------';


        select count(1) into _total from my_table where my_new_column is null;
        raise notice '  Total to process: %', _total;

        if (_total = 0) then
            _is_done = true;
        end if;

        _start_time := clock_timestamp();

        while (not _is_done) loop
            raise notice '  ------------------------------------------------------';
            _i_start_time := clock_timestamp();

            create table _auxiliar as
            select t.id, t2.column_b
            from my_table t
                join my_table_2 t2 on t.column_a = t2.id
            where t.my_new_column is null
            limit _chunk_size
            ;

            if ((select count(1) from _auxiliar) = 0) then
                _is_done := true;
            else
                raise notice '  Iteration: %...', _index;
                raise notice '  %/% - To Process now: % rows.', _processed, _total, (select count(1) from _auxiliar);

                update my_table t
                set my_new_column = _a.column_b
                from _auxiliar _a
                where t.id = _a.id;

                _processed := _processed + (select count(1) from _auxiliar);

                _i_end_time := clock_timestamp();
                _i_delta := extract(epoch from _i_end_time) - extract(epoch from _i_start_time );
                raise notice '  Iteration % Done! (% seconds)', _index, (SELECT round(_i_delta::numeric, 5));
            end if;

            drop table _auxiliar;
            _index := _index + 1;
            commit;
        end loop;

        raise notice '------------------------------------------------------';

        _end_time := clock_timestamp();
        _delta := extract(epoch from _end_time) - extract(epoch from _start_time );

        raise notice 'Done! Processed: % in % seconds', _processed, (SELECT round(_delta::numeric, 5));
    end;
$$;

-- Call the procedure.
call set_my_new_column_in_my_table();

-- Drop the procedure.
drop procedure if exists set_my_new_column_in_my_table();
```

Everything goes well but in a specific moment this happens:

```
    Iteration: 2657...
    13280000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2657 Done! (2.28732 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2658...
    13285000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2658 Done! (2.24910 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2659...
    13290000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2659 Done! (2.35870 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2660...
    13295000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2660 Done! (2.12086 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2661...
    13300000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2661 Done! (35.90165 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2662...
    13305000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2662 Done! (25.38119 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2663...
    13310000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2663 Done! (13.67274 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2664...
    13315000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2664 Done! (13.16674 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2665...
    13320000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2665 Done! (10.93982 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2666...
    13325000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2666 Done! (9.37919 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2667...
    13330000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2667 Done! (14.13303 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2668...
    13335000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2668 Done! (11.63840 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2669...
    13340000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2669 Done! (10.27763 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 2670...
    13345000/29047591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 2670 Done! (12.65083 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
```

The iterations that were taking between 1 sec and 2 secs after 13M of rows start taking more than 10 secs. During the execution, the CPU was around 60% and after that it goes down until 20% and it never come back to increase.

I decided to stop the process and I noted an autovacuum with analyze started. So I believe "maybe my database needs a breath to organice its life". After finishing, I run the Procedure again but I noted the same pattern but after the row ~640000

```
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 127...
    630000/15067591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 127 Done! (1.83836 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 128...
    635000/15067591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 128 Done! (1.82337 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 129...
    640000/15067591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 129 Done! (1.85929 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 130...
    645000/15067591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 130 Done! (1.80336 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 131...
    650000/15067591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 131 Done! (17.37781 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 132...
    655000/15067591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 132 Done! (33.76992 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 133...
    660000/15067591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 133 Done! (14.81248 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    Iteration: 134...
    665000/15067591 - To Process now: 5000 rows.
    Iteration 134 Done! (9.34563 seconds)
    ------------------------------------------------------
```

I know I can recreate the table and it will be a faster process but on the other hand, I really would like to understand what is happening here and what I am doing wrong.

I am running this test over am AWS Postgres RDS 13.3.

Any Ideas?

Thanks on advance!

Comment: You can start by looking at the contents of `pg_stat_bgwriter` to see if the number of checkpoint requests is too high. By the way, the batch size of 5000 rows is probably too low, especially considering you create and drop a work table (which you don't really need) on every iteration.

Comment: Have you tried doing this update in one statement rather than row-by-row? Is this something you need to do often, or a one-off? Another approach for a one off is to create a new table with the updated data and then swap it with the original table.

Comment: I don't see the advantage of chunking from within a function. A function inherently creates a transaction, if it's not already running in one. So, from my (somewhat superficial) intuition, it would seem that this would be much quicker in a single statement, since the function's implicit transaction is going to cause a new snapshot to be made, which is not going to be committed until after _all_ your chunks have been updated.

Comment: Also, I would check your assumptions about nasty locks being caused by this statement. As long as there are no complicated triggers on the table and there's no index on the new column, I don't see why much locking would be needed. (But, again, I'm not giving an answer, merely indicating a direction to test/investigate, since I'm pretty ignorant on Postgres locking.)